In R, parameter check when passing a function to another function as an input
In R, if I pass a function to another function as an input (as in stackoverflow.com/questions/74044185), how can I parameter check the function? As a minimal example, this function requires the passed function to be either NULL (do nothing), upper.tri or lower.tri
mytri <- function(tri.func = NULL){
  test <- matrix(1:25,5,5)
  if(is.function(tri.func)){
     test[!tri.func(test)] <-NA
  }
  return(test)
}
mytri()
mytri(upper.tri)
mytri(lower.tri)

But how do I check that the function is in my allowed list? For example mytri(log) will return the wrong result without error. I tried  if(is.function(tri.func) && all(names(formals(tri.func)) ==c("x","diag"))) but that doesn't work because  apparently all(logical(0) == c("x", "diag")) is TRUE

Are you looking for the 1st example in match.arg?

Thanks, yes , that would work if I was to rewrite the code with a conditional switch or if-else and pass the parameter as a character string. But I wasn't looking for an alternative way to get the same result.  In principle , and without changing any other code, is there any logical check that can be added to the if statement?

Like I say in my comment to the question, the first example in match.arg can be adapted to this problem. The main twist is the possibility of a missing argument, the NULL default in the question. Here I test it with missing.
mytri <- function(tri.func = c("upper.tri", "lower.tri")) {
  test <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5)
  if(!missing(tri.func)) {
    tri.func <- match.arg(tri.func)
    i <- switch(tri.func,
                upper.tri = upper.tri(test),
                lower.tri = lower.tri(test))
    test[i] <- NA
  }
  test
}

mytri()
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
#> [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
#> [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
#> [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
#> [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
mytri("upper.tri")
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]    2    7   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]    3    8   13   NA   NA
#> [4,]    4    9   14   19   NA
#> [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
mytri("lower.tri")
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
#> [2,]   NA    7   12   17   22
#> [3,]   NA   NA   13   18   23
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   19   24
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   25
mytri("log")
#> Error in match.arg(tri.func): 'arg' should be one of "upper.tri", "lower.tri"

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Edit
To answer to the comment

But I wasn't looking for an alternative way to get the same result. In principle , and without changing any other code, is there any logical check that can be added to the if statement in my question?

here is a version with an added logical test. The new test is a series of identical checks because %in% and == do not work with function objects.
When the function is not one of the allowed functions an error trappable with try or tryCatch is thrown.
mytri <- function(tri.func = NULL) {
  test <- matrix(1:25,5,5)
  if(is.function(tri.func) && 
     (identical(tri.func, lower.tri) || identical(tri.func, upper.tri))) {
    test[!tri.func(test)] <-NA
  } else if(!is.null(tri.func)) {
    f <- deparse(substitute(tri.func))
    msg <- sprintf("'%s' not an allowed function.", f)
    stop(msg)
  }
  test
}

mytri()
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
#> [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
#> [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
#> [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
#> [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
mytri(upper.tri)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]   NA    6   11   16   21
#> [2,]   NA   NA   12   17   22
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   18   23
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   24
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
mytri(lower.tri)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]    3    8   NA   NA   NA
#> [4,]    4    9   14   NA   NA
#> [5,]    5   10   15   20   NA
mytri(log)
#> Error in mytri(log): 'log' not an allowed function.

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks, yes , that works, But I wasn't looking for an alternative way to get the same result. In principle , and without changing any other code, is there any logical check that can be added to the if statement in my question?

@moreQthanA See if the edit is what you want.
